# ¿Cómo pongo de fondo una imagen?

Tags: java, imagen, interfaz-gráfica, bluej

Quiero poner de fondo una imagen en mi interfaz, la pregunta es simplemente esa.

Creo que el problema mío es localizar la imagen, ya intente con un montón de códigos. Actualmente estoy usando [Bluej](https://bluej.org/).
Ya tengo una interfaz creada solo quiero ponerle una cancha DE FONDO como la que dejo de ejemplo. (con los `label` encima y eso).

Agradezco su ayuda.

```
    public VerOnce()
    {
        super("11 del equipo");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


        l1= new JLabel("");
        l2= new JLabel("");
        l3= new JLabel("");
        l4= new JLabel("");
        l5= new JLabel("");
        l6= new JLabel(" ");
        l7= new JLabel(" ");
        l8= new JLabel("");
        l9= new JLabel("");
        l10= new JLabel("");
        l11= new JLabel("");
        l12= new JLabel ("");
        l13= new JLabel ("");

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy= 1;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l3, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l4, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy= 3;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l5, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy= 3;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l6, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l7, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l8, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l9, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l10, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy= 5;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l11, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l12, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l13, gbc);

    }
}
```

ACTUAL INTERFAZ
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

FONDO QUE QUIERO UTLIZAR
[image: cancha]

Como resultado deberia quedar algo asi (SOLO LOS NOMBRES).

[image: resultado]

Comment: Hola Yeison, tal y como está redactada la pregunta ahora mismo, es bastante amplia. Por favor edita la pregunta para dar algo más de contexto: ¿qué es lo que has intentado? ¿qué errores/dificultades encontrabas? ¿Cuál es tu código actual? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro añado imagen de la interfez y codigo que tengo, quiero que de fondo se ponga una imagen de una cancha de futbol no ese fondo blanco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo mi versión de la clase **VerOnce**, las etiquetas no se si quedan como vos querias, si no es así, lo mejor sería usar el método paint() para tener mayor control de los nombres:

```
public class VerOnce extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel l1;
    private JLabel l2;
    private JLabel l3;
    private JLabel l4;
    private JLabel l5;
    private JLabel l6;
    private JLabel l7;
    private JLabel l8;
    private JLabel l9;
    private JLabel l10;
    private JLabel l11;
    private JLabel l12;
    private JLabel l13;
    public VerOnce()
    {
        super("11 del equipo");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // AQUI INGRESO LA IMAGEN
        BufferedImage img;
        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("background.png"));

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
            setSize(dim);
            setMinimumSize(dim);
            setMaximumSize(dim);
            setResizable(false);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // AHORA INGRESO LOS LABELS
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        l1= new JLabel("LABEL-1");
        l2= new JLabel("LABEL-2");
        l3= new JLabel("LABEL-3");
        l4= new JLabel("LABEL-4");
        l5= new JLabel("LABEL-5");
        l6= new JLabel("LABEL-6");
        l7= new JLabel("LABEL-7");
        l8= new JLabel("LABEL-8");
        l9= new JLabel("LABEL-9");
        l10= new JLabel("LABEL-10");
        l11= new JLabel("LABEL-11");
        l12= new JLabel("LABEL-12");
        l13= new JLabel("LABEL-13");

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy= 1;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l3, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l4, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy= 3;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l5, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy= 3;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l6, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l7, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l8, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l9, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l10, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy= 5;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l11, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy= 4;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l12, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy= 2;
        gbc.gridwidth= 1;
        gbc.gridheight= 1;
        gbc.weightx= 1.0;
        gbc.weighty= 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(l13, gbc);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new VerOnce();
    }
}
```

A mi me queda de la siguiente forma, giré la imagen, teniendo en cuenta la ultima foto que me pusistes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, si pudieras explicarme te agradecía, si verOnce extiende JFrame. Edito mi pregunta nuevamente mejor explicada.

Comment: Si me pones los add que utilizas para los JLabel's, modifico la respuesta con todo el constructor

Comment: ahi puse todos, resaltar que los ultimos label son vacios para acomodar la interfaz y que los jugadores los lleno desde otro clase con su settext

Comment: Ya deje la actualizacion, pero los labels, ocupa todo el JFrame y no quedan bien alineados, no se si es asi como lo queres o que ocupe solo la mitad de la cancha, yo te aconsejaria usar el metodo paint() para tener mayor control de lo que se pinta en pantalla.